Merging lines in QGIS (like topo maps)
I have two shapefiles in QGIS containing polylines. One has 7 meter wide lines and the other has 5 meter wide lines. They currently exist on different layers, making intersections look like they are on different layers. How do I join them together to make them look like branches off of a main road instead of bridges?
